ConnectionTimeout downloading from ADLS2/Blob storage
I have implemented an azure function app (HTTP trigger) with python3, which needs to download a blob from azure ADLS2 blob storage (source data for an operation). The HTTP trigger gets a POST with JSON body, which contains the URL to the BLOB in question.
When running the function on a debugger, the BLOB download works flawlessly. However, when deployed into azure, about every 50% of times the BLOB download using the requests.get fails with ConnectionTimeout error. I tried to avoid the issue by making the timeout short (5s) and retrying for five times, but if it fails once, it seems to fail always. A couple of minutes later, the same operation succeeds and takes less than a second.
I've tried to google for the solution, but I can't find anything relevant. Any ideas?
Edit: I added retries so that requests.get() is tried 100 times with 3s timeout. The result is that when it fails, all 100 retries fail. At the same time as the request is failing exact same URL from a browser succesfully downloads the BLOB.

Increase the function timeout in host.json "functionTimeout":"00:30:00".

My http get uses 3s timeout (see edit above) and it's the first operation in the function. If the get fails once, it fails all the time.

Connect the Azure function App to Application insights and track the logs to analyze the issue behind connection timeout.
Increase the functionTimeout in host.json:
{
  "functionTimeout":"00:30:00"
}

Use below code to download blob from ADLS2/Blob storage:
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import os
import json

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    blob_name = req.params.get('blob_name')
    if not blob_name:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please provide a 'blob_name' parameter in the query string.",
            status_code=400
        )
    else:
        blob_connect_str = os.environ["StorageAccountConnectionString"]
        blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(blob_connect_str)
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="container", blob=blob_name)

        try:
            blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()
            binary_data = blob_data.readall()

            return func.HttpResponse("Downloaded the file successfully.", status_code=200)

        except Exception as e:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)

Deployed to Azure function app.
Able to run the deployed function:


Output:
2024-10-21T13:26:45Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.http_trigger' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=84077372-207d-4248-b988-ff4542a36b4e)
2024-10-21T13:26:45Z   [Verbose]   Sending invocation id: '84077372-207d-4248-b988-ff4542a36b4e
2024-10-21T13:26:45Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation id:84077372-207d-4248-b988-ff4542a36b4e on workerId:d24c1688-b527-4045-87d8-64d17257cc2a
2024-10-21T13:26:45Z   [Information]   Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2024-10-21T13:26:45Z   [Information]   Request URL: 'https://storagename.blob.core.windows.net/container/Hello%20World.txt'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
    'x-ms-range': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'Accept': 'application/xml'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.23.1 Python/3.11.9 (Linux-5.10.102.2-microsoft-standard-x86_64-with-glibc2.31)'
    'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '1ddf1f08-8fb0-11ef-bfb7-00155d54f124'
    'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
No body was attached to the request
2024-10-21T13:26:45Z   [Information]   Response status: 206
Response headers:
    'Content-Length': '11'
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    'Content-Range': 'REDACTED'
    'Last-Modified': 'Mon, 21 Oct 2024 12:38:25 GMT'
    'Accept-Ranges': 'REDACTED'
    'ETag': '"0x8DCF1CD418FC184"'
    'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
    'x-ms-request-id': '31832257-401e-0019-51bc-23ce13000000'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '1ddf1f08-8fb0-11ef-bfb7-00155d54f124'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-creation-time': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-blob-content-md5': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-lease-status': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-lease-state': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-blob-type': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-server-encrypted': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Mon, 21 Oct 2024 13:26:44 GMT'
2024-10-21T13:26:45Z   [Information]   Executed 'Functions.http_trigger' (Succeeded, Id=84077372-207d-4248-b988-ff4542a36b4e, Duration=98ms)


I managed to "fix" the issue by relocating the blob storage to the same data center than the functions. Now everything works fine. However, I can't figure out why sometimes the connection fails (doesn't get any HTTP response) between "North Europe" and "Sweden" datacenters, when accessing blob from outside Azure works fine.

Can you try with the code provided in the answer above?
